# Submit checkbox by jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

In a form I working on there are plenty of checkboxes. I want to use jquery ajax in order to post the value every time user clicks on a checkbox. It should be something like the code below but I am not sure. It is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".autosubmit_checkbox").click(function() {

    var value = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).attr('name');;
    var dataString = 'value=' + value + '&name=' + name;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            something;
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you use asp.net ? asp:checkbox ?

Comment: Well for one thing, URL needs to point to a web address. Also, you shouldn't do `$(this)` twice in the same function. Do this `var $this = $(this);` Then just use `$this` instead.

Comment: Also you didn't say what specifically isn't working.

Comment: What's not working? The ajax request isn't firing?

Comment: RoyiNamir, I use HTML<br/>

@Zero21xxx URL points to web address but I edited there. I will consider your advice.

And, yes, ajax request isn't firing. Also I can't check the checkboxes specified with this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit the check box's value in the query string in the "usual" way, you have to build a single request argument:

```
var dataString = $(this).attr('name') + "=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
```

[serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) would compute this string for you, but it returns an empty string if the check box is unchecked, which is apparently not what you want.

Comment: thank you, it should work. However there is a minor problem, I can't check the checkbox. What might be the problem?

Comment: @Farhad, that's because you're returning `false` from your `click` handler, thus preventing the default behavior to take place (and also preventing the event from bubbling up).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".autosubmit_checkbox").click(function() {

    var value = $(this).is(':checked')?"1":"0";
    var name = $(this).attr('name');;
    var dataString = 'value=' + value + '&name=' + name;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            something;
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).is(':checked')` instead of `$(this).val()` and avoid returning `false`, as it will prevent the checkbox from actually being checked (unless it is the behavior you want).